# R how to replace substrings within a longer string with a new substring

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a long vector. Each element is a string.
Each string can be split into substrings separated by ', '.

I want to check if each string in my vector contains at least one 'bad' string. If it does, then the whole SUBstring that contains that 'bad' string should be replaced with a new string. I've written a long function with loops. But I could swear there must be an easier way of doing it - maybe with stringr? 
Thank you so much for your advice!

```
# Create an example data frame:
test <- data.frame(a = c("str1_element_1_aaa, str1_element_2",
                         "str2_element_1",
                         "str3_element_1, str3_element_2_aaa, str3_element_3"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
test
str(test)

# Defining my long function that checks if each string in a
# vector contains a substring with a "bad" string in it.
# If it does, that whole substring is replaced with a new string:
library(stringr)
mystring_replace = function(strings_vector, badstring, newstring){
  with_string <- grepl(badstring, strings_vector)  # what elements contain badstring?
  mysplits <- str_split(string = test$a[with_string], pattern = ', ') # split those elements with badstring based on ', '
  for (i in 1:length(mysplits)) {   # loop through the list of splits:
    allstrings <- mysplits[[i]]
    for (ii in 1:length(allstrings)) {  # loop through substrings
      if (grepl(badstring, allstrings[ii])) mysplits[[i]][ii] <- newstring
    }
  }
  for (i in seq_along(mysplits)) {  # merge the split elements back together
    mysplits[[i]] <- paste(mysplits[[i]], collapse = ", ")
  }
  strings_vector[with_string] <- unlist(mysplits)
  return(strings_vector)
}
# Test
mystring_replace(test$a, badstring = '_aaa', newstring = "NEW")
```

Comment: Instead of using 3 for loops you could split on a bad string and join on a good string.

Comment: Good idea, but this is not going to help me. I don't want to join on a good string. I want to REPLACE the WHOLE substring that contains a bad string with a new substring.

Answer (score 1):

Think this may do it?

```
new_str_replace <- function(strings_vector, badstring, newstring){
  split.dat <- strsplit(strings_vector,', ')[[1]]
  split.dat[grepl(badstring, split.dat)] <- newstring
  return(paste(split.dat, collapse = ', '))
}

results <- unname(sapply(test$a, new_str_replace, badstring = '_aaa', newstring = 'NEW'))
results
#[1] "NEW, str1_element_2"                 "str2_element_1"                     
#[3] "str3_element_1, NEW, str3_element_3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it with a divide-an-conquer fashion. First I wrote a function that does the operation for one string only, and then vectorized it.

```
# does the operation for a string only. divide-and-conquer
replace_one = function(string, badstring, newstring) {
  # split it at ", "
  strs = str_split(string, ", ")[[1]]
  # an ifelse to find the ones containing badstring and replacing them
  strs = ifelse(grepl(badstring, strs, fixed = TRUE), newstring, strs)
  # join them again
  paste0(strs, collapse = ", ")
}

# vectorizes it
my_replace = Vectorize(replace_one, "string", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses the `tidyverse`, `purrr`, and `stringr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Small utility function
find_and_replace <- function(string, bad_string, replacement_string) {
  ifelse(str_detect(string, bad_string), replacement_string, string)
}

str_split(test$a, ", ") %>%                 
  map(find_and_replace, "aaa", "NEW") %>%   
  map_chr(paste, collapse = ", ") %>%
  unlist
```

Basically: split the vector into a list, map `find_and_replace` over that list, and collapse the results. I would recommend looking at the results individually after each pipe `%>%`.

Comment: I love it! Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Weird, I put it in a function, but it's not working properly:

Comment: # Small utility function
find_and_replace <- function(string, bad_string, replacement_string) {
  ifelse(str_detect(string, bad_string), replacement_string, string)
}
# function:
string_replace_n <- function(mystring, mybad_string, myreplacement){
  out <- str_split(mystring, ", ") %>%                 
    map(find_and_replace, mybad_string, myreplacement) %>%   
    map_chr(paste, collapse = ", ") %>% unlist
  out
}

Comment: @user3245256 apologize -- you need to also load the `stringr` package via `library(stringr)`. Updated the code -- probably safe to delete these comments once its working on your end.